# Content-Length is randomly null

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-headers, httpclient

I'm trying to download from a specific URL using this code:

```
var requestUri = "https://github.com/gus33000/MSM8994-8992-NT-ARM64-Drivers/archive/master.zip";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
    }
}
```

If you run the code, you will likely get `null` in `contentLength`. But, why? Sometimes, the length is returned. What should I do to retrieve the length of the file always?

Comment: Probably nothing. Just download, independent of the returned length.

Comment: The problem is that the file is really big. I'm using progress reporting to give the user feedback about the % completed. Having no total size is a true problem :(

Comment: It depends on the server you download files from. If they set the header, you can use it. If they don't... You can't

Comment: You are probably exceeding the time out.

Comment: Firefox doesn't know either. The headers are simply not set. In these cases, I usually do what the WebBrowsers do: show a marquee and the download progression in bytes. Something to look at. With a `Cancel` button nearby.

Comment: @jdweng  `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. This request returns almost immediately.

Comment: Are you getting a status back 200 or something else when it fails?

Comment: @jdweng the download is OK, and the headers are returned right away, but most of times (90% of times) the Content Length comes empty.

Comment: I usually consider random when it works most of the time and occasionally fails.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see if issue is the response from the server or the c# code.  Check if you are using http 1.0 (stream mode) or http 1.1 (chunk mode).  And the status returned.  Without knowing the status it is hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @SuperJMN - Did you find solution for this problem, I am facing exactly same problem only that for me it fails once in every 10 minutes.

Comment: I've found that server like the ones that GitHub uses to host content, usually don't report the content-lenght, so you need to be ready to make the download mechanism fail-proof. Please, refer to my Downloader class to see how I overcome the issue: https://github.com/SuperJMN-Zafiro/Zafiro/blob/master/Source/Zafiro.Core/Downloader.cs